# ossec updated to 2.9.0 on centos 6 via atomic repo - won't start

Tags: centos6, ossec

I've had the atomic repo and ossec installed for a few years.  It recently updated to 2.9.0 from 2.8.3 and it removed /var/ossec/bin/ossec-control.  Now ossec won't start.

I ran "yum whatprovides */ossec-control" and its saying ossec-hids-hybrid-2.9.0...  I tried to install that, but that conflicts with ossec-hids-agent-2.9.0.

Has anyone sorted through this?  Do I need to remove "agent" and install "hybrid"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue on my agents - but I ended up re-installing the ossec-hids-agent and it fixed the issue for me.

I was upgrading and replacing 'ossec-hids-client' with 'ossec-hids-agent',BTW.

Comment: Yes, I did similar, but i kept ossec-hids-client.  yum remove ossec*; yum install ossec-hids ossec-hids-client; and then added my ossec server ip to /var/ossec/etc/ossec-agent.conf and ossec started up successfully again.